# not understanding plt.plot(train_x, regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0], '-r') in ML

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, regression

```
plt.scatter(train.ENGINESIZE, train.CO2EMISSIONS,  color='blue')
plt.plot(train_x, regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0], '-r') **--this line**
plt.xlabel("Engine size")
plt.ylabel("Emission")
```

What is the meaning of this syntax?
`train_x` is the EngineSize vs formula ie. `theta0+theta1*~x(mean)`
but what is this -r in the syntax & then how is it plotting...
Kindly someone elaborately explain me dis

Comment: [The third argument of `plot` is the format string.](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot). It specifies the look of the plot, that is, what color, line shape and marker size to use. `-` means solid line, `r` means red color.

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.scatter(train.ENGINESIZE, train.CO2EMISSIONS,  color='blue')
plt.plot(train_x, regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0], '-r'))'
before explain the code above let me clear that
**The linear regression equation** is the below :\

> **y=a+bx**\

**a: intercept

b: sloop/gradient(coefficient)** 
back to the code, it is simply  a scatter plot between **the actual values**  and **the predicted values** to compare **the accuracy of a regression model**.

the part

> **regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0]**

**regr.coef_**: this is a list variable that holds the b variable (coefficient) , so regr.coef_[0][0] aiming to select only the first value in the  list which is the coefficient.
**regr.intercept_**:it is also a list but it holds the a variable (intercept).\

> The conclusion is that:

**regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0]    is equevelant    to y=a+bx**

> '-r' : This is the line color in the plot 
> you can use  '-y' :for yellow or  '-b' for blue

I wish this makes it clear to you :).

Answer (score 0):

This syntax may be difficult to understand because **train_x** is not just one x value.

**train_x** is an **ndarray** (or a subclass of ndarray), which is a set of values. So this syntax appears to suggest we are multiplying a single value (the slope coefficient **regr.coef_[0][0]**) by an N-dimensional array (**train_x**).

This is indeed what is happening. When using Numpy you can multiply EVERY value in an array by a scalar (a single number with only magnitude) using only the normal multiplication operator **( * )**. This also applies to the addition of the single y-intercept using the addition operator **( + )**.

This is particularly confusing because we are passing:

1. **train_x** (the ndarray made from the input values in the training data)
2. a new **ndarray** (result of multiplying each element by slope & adding y-intercept)
3. and **"-r"** the string to set the **color**

It also is confusing because passing those two arrays one might expect a red dot representing the approximated output by the module for each input value in the training data. However, the **plot()** method on **matplotlib.pyplot** (imported in the example above as **plt**) draws a line, in this case the models **fit line** using the three  parameters listed above.

We know that the equation of a line is given as **y = mx + b** but the fit line of the data in linear regression is given as **y = θ<sub>0</sub> + θ<sub>1</sub>x<sub>0~n</sub>** (where **x<sub>0~n</sub>** is the set of all inputs, **θ<sub>1</sub>** is the slope and **θ<sub>0</sub>** is the intercept). This is likely why the parameters to **plot()** have been chosen in this way, despite the plot method drawing a continuous line from the first value expected/approximated value through the last one.

[image: image of plot from IBM AI course that the OP's question comes from]

Answer (score 0):

train_x is ndarray made from the input values in the training data.       It is also confusing because here we are passing direct ndarray (the result of multiplying each element by slope and and adding y-intercept. Secondly, the plot() method (imported as plt from matplotlib.pyplot) draw a line due to parameters(intercept & coefficients) used already calculated for linear regression model.

Answer (score -1):

This is the function for plot the trainning sets(blue points):

```py
plt.scatter(train.ENGINESIZE, train.CO2EMISSIONS,  color='blue')
```

This is the function for plot the equation or the model (red line):

```py
plt.plot(train_x, regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0], '-r')
```

In plot function you need to specify `(X,Y)` for plotting. So `X = Train_x(ENGINESIZE Values)` and `Y = the equation (Y=0º+0¹X) -> 0º=regr.intercept_[0]` and `0¹= regr.coef_[0][0]`

In other words: **`plt.plot(X,0º+0¹*X,'-r')`**

`'r -> color of line: red`

I hope this explanation helps you. Good Luck!